# using fancybox plugin to make an image gallery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's wrong with the script order given below? I used fancybox to view images on my website but it doesn't work. Can it be that the script order is wrong or there are conflicts? I want to make an image gallery with fanybox plugin.

This is the error that I got :

`Timestamp: 3/22/2013 2:25:05 PM
Error: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Source File: file:///G:/LBC-FIRM/example.com/js/jquery.fancybox.js
Line: 1985`

This is the order of my script references:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tooltip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/image_groups.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/thumbnail-slider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.noConflict();
    </script>
```

My HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#royal_place").click(function(){
    $.fancybox.open([
        {href : '../object/royal_palace/1.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/2.jpg'}, 
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/3.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/4.jpg'}, 
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/5.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/6.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/7.jpg'}, 
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/8.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/9.jpg'},
    {href : '../object/royal_palace/10.jpg'}
     ]);
      });           
   });
</script>

<a id="royal_place" href="javascript:;" >
    <img src="img/pic_tuk_tuk_1.png" alt="Tuk Tuk picture One" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'Tuk Tuk one')"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: what is at jquery.fancybox.js Line: 1985 ? @phireak

Comment: Timestamp: 3/22/2013 2:56:33 PM
Error: TypeError: $.fancybox.open is not a function
Source File: file:///G:/LBC-FIRM/bunnat-transport.com/js/image_groups.js
Line: 4

Comment: @phireak try putting `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>` after all scripts

Comment: I placed it after all my scripts file include but it still doesn't work for me

Comment: hmm. i am out of ideas. hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: thank btevfik for your time and solution for me even it can't solve but still thank you. good luck.